# SharePoint 2010 Custom List Form Tool Tip Field Help

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a custom form in sharepoint and I need to add to formatted field help on mouseover, what is a good way to accomplish this?

STandard tooltips go away to fast..

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: It looks like a giant pain in the neck, but this guy figured out a way to do it in custom forms: http://johnliu.net/blog/2011/11/10/infopath-managing-lots-of-tooltip-in-your-browser-form.html

Comment: That is using Infopath unfortunately we are using SharePoint designer.  I use to use a very cool tool called overlib but seem that does not work with sharepoint.

Comment: Would the new JSON column formatting tool let you do it? (caveat: I know *nothing* about JSON. Less than that, even.)